# Strange UINavigationController push behavior due to custom UIFont

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationbar

I have changed the font of the `UINavigationBar` using **'appearance'** available in **iOS5**. But when doing a push transition to another view controller (**using Storyboard**) it goes wrong.

During the transition, normally you can see **'fade in'** the next `UIViewController`'s title, but now all **I see is 'F...' and only at the end of the transition the whole title shows up: 'Facebook sharing' (instead of immediately).**

Anyone who has had this problem before? This doesn't happen when there's a `UIBarButton` on the right of the `UINavigationBar`. Then everything goes fine.

I set the font like this:

```
UIFont *fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:0];
NSDictionary *font = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontName, UITextAttributeFont, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:font];
```

Comment: I found this font on this site: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: Also, I noticed when changing the font of a `UIBarButtonitem`, there's **a little shock in the position of the right button at the end of the transition.** Only happens if the font is too large (even set with size '0').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got away using a **fixed font size** instead of **'0'**:

```
UIFont *fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:18];
```

Now it works like a charm. The app will only be running in **portrait orientation**, otherwise I guess the **font size should be set every time the device rotates**.

Comment: It makes sense, because calculating the size of any text at a point size of zero yields 0 by 0 pixels, thus you're showing `F...` because of clipping.

Comment: I did the same in my app however my app has multiple orientations. How can I change the font when the app turns orientation, say in - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: Doesn't this work `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`? But using an actual font size instead of `0`.